# Надо ли закавычивать "сверху"?

Tags: кавычки

Все эти преобразования «сверху», в сущности, коснулись лишь...
Надо ли закавычивать "сверху"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кавычки не нужны — переносное значение слова давно зафиксировано словарями ([звонок сверху](https://sovdep.academic.ru/3394/%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%85%D1%83)).

В толковом словаре (С. И. Ожегов, Н. Ю. Шведова):
**сверху**
3. *наречие, перен.* Со стороны руководящих органов. **Директива сверху.**

В словаре Д. Н. Ушакова:
[сверху](https://glosum.ru/%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%85%D1%83)
4. *нареч. перен.* По почину правительства, руководящих органов, по направлению от них к массам или к подчиненным инстанциям (*книж.*). **Распоряжения сверху.**
*Своеобразие этой революции состояло в том, что она была произведена **сверху**, по инициативе государственной власти, при прямой поддержке снизу со стороны миллионных масс крестьян, боровшихся против кулацкой кабалы, за свободную колхозную жизнь* (История ВКП(б)).

[Петр I] *начал свое преобразование сверху, а не снизу, с вельмож, а не с мужиков* (В. Г. Белинский. Россия до Петра Великого).